# Check whether the query executed or not

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this php code using PDO

```
$q = "START TRANSACTION;";
$q = "INSERT INTO `student` (`first_name`, `last_name`, `level`) VALUES ('Zac', 'Mark',2);";
$q.= " SET @lastId = (SELECT `id` FROM `student` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1);";  
$q .= " INSERT INTO `student_dep` (`stdnt_id`, `dep_id`) VALUES (@lastId, 2);";
$q .= " COMMIT;";  
$db->query($q);
$check = $db->execute();
if($check){
   echo "1";
}else{
  echo "2";
}
```

Now this query isn't right so it suppose to return false;
but it returns true and it doesn't execute.
How can I check whether it's executed or not?

Comment: Apart from doing absolutely everything wrong you could, how come you even get something back? `$db` is `PDO` instance, therefore - it can't have `execute()` method. Do you want to fix this to work properly with PDO or do  you want to keep trying your own method?

Comment: @N.B., `$db` is an object of a PDO connection class and execute() and query() are methods that I declared in that class

Answer (score 2):

Your code can't work, because you're invoking the `execute` method on a `PDO` object. `PDOStatement` contains `execute` method so I'll guess that you lost something in all the copy pasting. Instead of answering your question, I'll show you the correct way of doing things which most people use.

1) **Create PDO object and set it in exception mode**

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

try 
{
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    $dbh>setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} 
catch (PDOException $e) 
{
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

2) **Prepare the statements**, start the transaction, bind values, execute

```
try
{
    // Prepare the insert for student table
    $student = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `student` (`first_name`, `last_name`, `level`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");

    // Prepare the insert for student_dep table
    $student_dep = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `student_dep` (`stdnt_id`, `dep_id`) VALUES (?, ?)");

    // Start the transaction
    $dbh->beginTransaction();

    // Create the record in student table
    $student->execute(['Zac', 'Mark', 2]);

    // Create the record ind student_dep table using the last insert id generated by previous insert
    $student_dep->execute([$dbh->lastInsertId(), 2]);

    // Commit both inserts
    $dbh->commit();
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    // If there was an active transaction, roll back
    if($dbh->inTransaction())
    {
        $dbh->rollBack();
    }
}
```

If anything goes south at any point, you'll receive an exception. Within the exception you do what you need to, such as reporting, rolling back, cleaning up etc. And this is the proper way to perform these things.

Comment: This code isn't rollback with me and I use InnoDB tables type

Comment: That's insufficient info to determine what's happening.

Comment: I just copy and past your code but I made the second query with non-exsist table name to rollback the first query but it didn't

Comment: Don't just copy paste the code, try to understand it. Did you **prepare** the query with nonexistent table or did you *execute* both queries and ended up with some records? You must be very clear in explaining how you determined that your queries are not rolled back. If you pasted the code from answer, it means you prepared two statements without inserting anything, so the transaction part never happens - therefore you can't roll back anything if there was no transaction.

Comment: I understand the code indeed, I execute two queries in the code, then I let the first one to execute and put the non-existent table in the second query so it rollBack the first one but it doesn't the first one executed and the second didn't so it didn't rollback

Answer (score 0):

You should execute each query separately, nstead that, you can use a Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER student_dep 
AFTER INSERT ON student
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
         INSERT INTO `student_dep` (`stdnt_id`, `dep_id`) 
         VALUES NEW.stdnt_id, NEW.level);
    END;
```

Comment: Now I have this code   

`try  
{  
 $db->query("CREATE TRIGGER student_dep   
    AFTER INSERT ON student  
    FOR EACH ROW  
        BEGIN  
             INSERT INTO `student_dep` (`stdnt_id`, `dep_id`)   
             VALUES (NEW.stdnt_id, 1);  
        END;");  
 $db->execute();  
    for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++){  
     $db->query("INSERT INTO student (`first_name`, `last_name`, `level`) values ('fname',lname',1)");  
     $db->execute();  
    }  
}  
catch(PDOException $e)  
{  
    echo $e->getMessage();  
}  `    

but it doesn't execute the trigger @Gioryo

Comment: You should create that trigger on your DB, better manually. Make it by code should do it on declaration and just if doesn't exists already.

Answer (score 0):

check will always have a value with respect to pdo, the best thing you can do is to do a lastInsertId() or fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) or fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) on your pdo i.e

```
$check = $db->lastInsertId() or
$check = $db->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) or
$check = $db->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
```

var_dump the value of check, if it is 0 then your insert failed, if not zero your data was inserted